# How to increase size of "legacy" UI on Win11?

Tags: windows-11, gui, zoom, dialog, size

I have a Surface Book 2 running Windows 11. It has a 3240x2160 resolution, so I've used both the Display's "scale" and Accessibility's "text size" features to zoom stuff in, and so far most things work out well. However, many old (and not-so-old) dialog boxes, such as "Run" and "Save as", are frustratingly small, to the point I can [hardly tell](https://imgur.com/a/f5PPPVR) what is what. I guess the features I used only apply to new, fancy Win11 GUI, not those legacies from previous versions. How to increase their sizes as well? Thanks.

Comment: Scale does the job for me on Windows 10 for these dialogs, and it should do the same for you. Something may be wrong.

Comment: my scale is already 225%, and i don't want to increase any further, otherwise the taskbar and stuff will look too bulky. yet the legacy boxes stay small.

Comment: For me  scale 225% also blows up these dialogs. They are not at all "legacy".

Comment: maybe there's a difference between win10 & 11? we may need some other opinions from w11 users to harden the statistics.